# Gravity Forms "gform_after_submission" CSS not working

Tags: wordpress, forms, hook, action, gravity

I have a code like this

```
add_action("gform_after_submission_3", "after_submission", 10, 2);
function after_submission($entry, $form){

$div_1 = $entry["6"]; // yes no
$div_2 = $entry["8"]; // yes no
......
enter code here
?>
<style>
        h1{ color: red; }
        tr.div td.lv_' . $div_lvl . '{ border: 4px solid #fd3c3d !important; }
    </style>
<h1>DEI Maturity Model</h1>
.....
<?php }
```

The HTML content gets displayed upon submission but the internal css I placed doesn't work.
What am I missing here?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Debugging_CSS

Comment: @jasie thanks for reply but it doesn't display the CSS in the dev tools nor in the sourcecode.